# python3 won't update to 3.9.1 by `apt` command

Tags: python-3.x

### Basic information

```
kali@kali:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.0
kali@kali:~$ uname -a
Linux kali 5.9.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.11-1kali1 (2020-12-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux
kali@kali:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

### Update, upgrade and dist-upgrade results

```
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

### The latest python3 version

from [python.org](https://www.python.org/)

[image]

### Question

Why my Python3 won't updated to the latest version (3.9.1) by the `apt` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately apt doesn't have the package at the moment. You will have to wait until it's added. You could compile from source using [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html)